# How to display output horizontally?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Pandas, After I use the for loop, the output is rotating and column is swapping with row's position. How can i still keep the output same as its in file?

```
for i in range(1,100):
    print(df.loc[(i*2)])
```

Comment: try to transpose `df.T`